# Setting up Custom Domain with Tumblr isn't working -- Correct A-record and CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, a-record

I'm setting up a custon domain to work with Tumblr. I configured A-record and CNAME correctly, but it still isn't working.

www.whatsmydns.net shows CORRECT A-record and CNAME for Tumblr: 66.6.44.4 and domains.tumblr.com

However, when I go to my custom domain, I am getting some "Is this domain name yours? Click here to manage your domain!" and it is not pulling from Tumblr.

Any advice?

Comment: What is the actual domain name?

Comment: This sounds as though the new DNS records hadn't propagated yet, so you were still getting a previous landing page for the domain.  Do you still have this problem today?

Answer (score 3):

The last time I used the term "DNS Propagation" I got rightfully downvoted off the internet... But DNS changes take a while to be refreshed through all relevant systems.

run `nslookup yourdomain.com` from the command line and see if it returns the tumblr address.

If it does not, it will either take time or there is an error in your configuration.